# collective.xdv - define an alternative theme breaks transform for default theme

Tags: plone, xdv

I'm using plone 4.0.1 + collective.xdv 1.0rc11 and I need to use different themes.

I'm trying to do as described [in a recent question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633951/collective-xdv-and-multiple-theme-files) but when I insert a new theme with a condition I get no transform at all for the default theme. Here are some examples of what I tried:

```
<rules css:if-content="body.section-mysection">
    <theme  href="mysection.html" />
</rules>
```

this ends in:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 132, in publish
  Module zope.event, line 23, in notify
  Module zope.component.event, line 26, in dispatch
  Module zope.component._api, line 138, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 323, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 575, in subscribers
  Module plone.transformchain.zpublisher, line 93, in applyTransformOnSuccess
TypeError
```

While these:

```
<theme  href="mysection.html" if-path="/mysection/"/>

<theme  href="mysection.html" css:if-content="body.section-mysection"/>
```

both work for the given section BUT for the rest of the portal there is no transform at all.

I tried to specify also the default theme in the rules.xml (even if it's already registered into @@xdv-settings) with `<theme href="index.html" />` but got no luck.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance,
SimO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would consider moving on to plone.app.theming. The upgrade/change is fairly trivial as I understand it (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.theming#migrating-from-collective-xdv)  and p.a.theming provides all the latest and greatest features that were developed under collective.xdv.

Second, I would reference this document:

- http://diazo.org/advanced.html#multiple-conditional-themes

It sounds like you just need to configure the default theme *first*, and then add a condition(s) to change the appropriate section when the condition matches. The additional matched theme should not affect the "default" (first matched) theme.

Comment: hi Alex, thanks! I'll try that but docs say "plone.app.theming works with Plone 4.1 or later.". Is there any workaround/backport that you know of?

Comment: Oh! No, sorry. I guess for < 4.1 collective.xdv is still the best choice.

Comment: It should be possible to get plone.app.theming to work with Plone 4.0 with an appropriate KGS, but I don't have the time to maintain that myself and Plone 4.1 is just around the corner.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your setup and your specific problem to the full extend, so I just post a working example. Note: we don't use a `default theme` value in the xdv control panel, since it will be obsolete with `plone.app.theming` anyway. It also seemed to interfere with setting up theme tempaltes in the rules.xml directly which might be relevant for your specific problem/usecase.

```
<rules
xmlns="http://namespaces.plone.org/xdv"
xmlns:css="http://namespaces.plone.org/xdv+css"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<theme css:if-content="body.section-front-page" href="frontpage.html"/>
<theme css:if-content="body.section-contact" href="contact.html"/>

<!-- Only style actual Plone page and exclude things like /manage -->
<rules css:if-content="#visual-portal-wrapper">

    <!-- default theme templates -->
    <theme href="theme.html" />
    <!-- Add your default transform rules here -->
    <rules css:if-content="body.section-contact">
        <!-- Theme template is already setup on top of this file -->
        <!-- Add section specific rules here -->
        <drop css:theme="#sidebar" />
    </rules>
</rules>
</rules>
```

These rules are as close as possible to the setup required by diazo/plone.app.theming and should just need minor adjustments (namespace correction and a search/replace  for `append`/`after` for example) - I just migrated the site this example has been lifted from to Plone4.1/diazo without any major drawbacks.

Comment: hi, I tried removing theme file settings from xdv-settings and I put this into my rules.xml`<theme href="index.html" />` `<theme href="index2.html" css:if-content="body.template-mytemplate" />` but it works only with the 2nd one. If I go anywhere else I get no transform at all :(