# is plone 4.1 (almost) ready for production?

Tags: plone

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882468/collective-xdv-define-an-alternative-theme-breaks-transform-for-default-theme) I'm going to try plone.app.theming which works with "Plone 4.1 or later".

The question is: how much far from a usable production version is plone 4.1 (currently 4.1b2)?

I had a look at the [bugs' list](http://dev.plone.org/plone/query?status=assigned&status=new&status=reopened&group=status&milestone=4.1) and it seems that there are no major blockers for that. Is that true?

Comment: Not really a question for stackoverflow.com, is it. Perhaps better asked at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: didn't know that... dumb question: is this the "official policy"?

Comment: It's the policy of Stack Overflow, see the [SO FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plone 4.1 should see a release candidate very soon (which will then become the final release). There's no known blockers left anymore. If you start working on a new site, definitely go for it. For upgrades of existing sites I'd wait a little bit longer until the final release is out.

Answer (score 3):

Currently running several smaller sites in production and a development version of a large touristic site (2 redundant servers, RelStorage with 16 Zopeclients) on Plone 4.1b2 without any issues so far.

Please note: the `plone.app.theming 1.0b1` release seems to set the `X-THEME-ENABLED` header a bit too globally and therefore using the header as a condition in the portal_css tool doesn't have the expected result and your stylesheets will be included when accessing the unthemed host as well.

Comment: Please file a ticket in the Plone issue tracker for the plone.app.theming issue if you haven't yet.